# MySQL queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Two quick (I hope!) questions:

**Counting rows**

Is it more efficient to use `COUNT(id)` in an SQL query, or to just select all the rows and use PHP's `mysql_num_rows()` function on the returned resource? Would this depend on the size of the results query? Is there a fairly easy way of determining the answer to this question?

**Results arrays**

At the moment, I am using `COUNT(id)` in a query, and then obviously using `mysql_query()` and `mysql_fetch_array()`, as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM TABLE1;";
$resource = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())
$result = mysql_fetch_array($resource);
$count = $result[0];
```

and this returns the number of rows fine.  However, I'm surprised that

```
$count = mysql_fetch_array($resource)[0];
```

doesn't work; I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\ServerDocs\file1.php on line 44
```

is there an easy explanation as to what's going on?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: PHP simply does not allow `function()[$array_index]`. It's a limitation to its syntax parser

Comment: Your second question: You're can't reference arrays like that as you can with JavaScript, unfortunately.

Comment: That feature (array-dereferncing) `function()[]` will be available in PHP 5.4

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, they're evil. Use PDO or mysqli

Comment: @JohnD: they're not evil, they're just a tool. Any tool can screw up if you don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends on the situation, but `SELECT COUNT(*)` is normally faster.
   The reason is simply that using `mysql_num_rows()`, the database
   server has to actually build the result set. With a `COUNT(*)`, on the
   other hand, the DB may be able to determine the number of rows just
   from indexes, which is much faster. So if all you want is the count,
   then `mysql_num_rows()` ends up doing a lot more work for the same
   result.

   Another down side is that mysql_num_rows doesn't work with
   unbuffered queries. So if you need to work with very large result
   sets, using mysql_num_rows might not be an option. However, `COUNT(*)`
   is always available.
2. `$count = mysql_fetch_array($resource)[0];`

   This type of statements are not possible in current version of php. 
    So, better use

   ```
   $no_of_rows = mysql_fetch_array($count);
   echo $no_of_rows[0];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1) mysql_query gets all the results and the you do a count on the results. Therefore performance is related to the number of results. If you do count(*) it is a DB select which results only one row/column. In this case database does everything for you, which is usually considered better.

2) `$count = mysql_fetch_array($count)[0];` is not possible. Do the following:

```
$count = mysql_fetch_array($count);
echo $count[0];
```